# How to formulate T-SQL to exclude duplicates?

Tags: t-sql, exists

I am trying to develop a query to just return non-duplicate records so that I can add these to my database, but I keep getting the duplicate record error.

I tried your solution but am still getting duplicate error problem.  I deleted the 35 rows which were duplicate.  What else could be causing this?  Here is my query.  Part of the confusion I think is that measureid is a single column in j5c_MasterMeasures, but this value comes from two fields in j5c_ListBoxMeasures_Sys.

```
CREATE TABLE #GOOD_RECORDS3 (STUDENTID VARCHAR(50), MEASUREDATE SMALLDATETIME, MEASUREID VARCHAR(100),
score_10 VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #GOOD_RECORDS3
select A.studentid, A.measuredate, B.measurename+' ' +B.LabelName, A.score_10
from [J5C_Measures_Sys] A join [J5C_ListBoxMeasures_Sys] B on A.MeasureID = B.MeasureID
except
select A.studentid, A.measuredate, B.measurename+' ' +B.LabelName, A.score_10
from [J5C_Measures_Sys] A join [J5C_ListBoxMeasures_Sys] B on A.MeasureID = B.MeasureID
GROUP BY A.studentid, A.measuredate, B.measurename, B.LabelName, A.score_10
having COUNT(A.score_10) > 1

delete #GOOD_RECORDS3
from #GOOD_RECORDS3 a
join sysobjects so on so.name = 'J5C_Measures_Sys' AND so.type = 'u'
join syscolumns sc on so.id = sc.id and sc.name = 'score_10'
join [J5C_MeasureNamesV2_Sys] v on v.Score_field_id = sc.name
WHERE A.SCORE_10 IS NOT NULL AND A.STUDENTID IS NOT NULL AND A.MEASUREID IS NOT NULL
and exists (select 1 from J5C_MasterMeasures M
 where M.StudentID = A.StudentID
and M.MeasureID = A.MeasureID)

Insert into J5C_MasterMeasures (studentid, measuredate, measureid, nce)
select A.studentid, A.measuredate, a.MEASUREID, A.score_10
from #GOOD_RECORDS3 a
join sysobjects so on so.name = 'J5C_Measures_Sys' AND so.type = 'u'
join syscolumns sc on so.id = sc.id and sc.name = 'score_10'
join [J5C_MeasureNamesV2_Sys] v on v.Score_field_id = sc.name
WHERE A.SCORE_10 IS NOT NULL AND A.STUDENTID IS NOT NULL AND A.MEASUREID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not menstioned the specifics of the unique constraint on `J5C_MasterMeasures`. Therefore, I assumed that all four columns being inserted were part of the constraint. In addition, your use of `Except` leads me to believe that you are using SQL Server 2005 or later. In addition, it is not clear how the join to `J5C_MeasureNamesV2_Sys` fits into the design or solution.

```
With GoodRecords As
    (
    Select A.StudentId
        , A.measuredate
        , B.measurename+ ' ' +B.LabelName
        , A.score_10 As NCE
    From [J5C_Measures_Sys] A 
        Join [J5C_ListBoxMeasures_Sys] B 
            On A.MeasureID = B.MeasureID
    Where A.StudentId Is Not Null
        And A.Score_10 Is Not Null
        And A.MeasureId Is Not Null
    Group By A.StudentId
        , A.MeasureDate
        , B.MeasureName+ ' ' +B.LabelName
        , A.score_10 
    Having Count(A.Score_10) = 0
    )
Insert J5C_MasterMeasures ( StudentId, MeasureData, MeasureId, NCE )
Select GR.StudentId, GR.MeasureData, GR.MeasureId, GR.NCE
From GoodRecords As GR
    Join [J5C_MeasureNamesV2_Sys] v 
        On v.Score_field_id = 'Score_10'
Where Not Exists    (
                    Select 1
                    From J5C_MasterMeasures As J1
                    Where J1.StudentId = GR.StudentId
                        And J1.MeasureData = GR.MeasureData
                        And J1.MeasureId = GR.MeasureId
                        And J1.NCE = GR.NCE
                    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Thomas.  However, when I run this query it returns 0 records.  Perhaps this is because only the first 3 columns comprise the Primary Key.  Yes, I am using SS 2008.  J5C_MeasureNamesV2_Sys is my lookup table--but not especially relevant for this question.